# Android: How to create vertical animation for FAB with BottomAppBar?

Tags: android, floating-action-button, android-bottomappbar

**BottomAppBar** widget from support library in **com.android.support** package has **isFabAttached** flag and method. In **28.0.0-alpha1** version it has public access. But after release of stable version **28.0.0** it is not available any more.

I used `bottomAppBar.isFabAttached = false` for animated detach and `bottomAppBar.isFabAttached = true` for vertical attach animations. But after update to com.android.support:design:28.0.0 `isFabAttached` has private access and as result animation doesn't work. Only horizontal animation is available for now.

How to animate fab button like on this picture for last release version of `com.android.support:design:28.0.0` library?

[image]

---

**UPDATE**: the issue resolved, I have copied the code from BottomAppBar and created a custom view: **CustomBottomAppBar** in the **android.support.design.bottomappbar** package and added next code:

```
public void setFabAttached(boolean attached) {
    maybeAnimateAttachChange(attached);
    maybeAnimateMenuView(fabAlignmentMode, attached);
    this.fabAttached = attached;
}

private void maybeAnimateAttachChange(boolean targetAttached) {
    if (fabAttached == targetAttached || !ViewCompat.isLaidOut(this)) {
        return;
    }

    if (attachAnimator != null) {
        attachAnimator.cancel();
    }

    List<Animator> animators = new ArrayList<>();

    createCradleShapeAnimation(targetAttached, animators);
    createFabTranslationYAnimation(targetAttached, animators);

    AnimatorSet set = new AnimatorSet();
    set.playTogether(animators);
    attachAnimator = set;
    attachAnimator.addListener(
            new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                    attachAnimator = null;
                }
            });
    attachAnimator.start();
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using reflection to access that field?

Comment: @NickMowen Thanks for the answer! No, didn't try the reflection. But I copied 2 classes: BottomAppBar and BottomAppBarTopEdgeTreatment and modified them. I hoped that there is a way to use default BottomAppBar.